# Where does this reccurence relation come from?

Tags: recurrence-relations

if$$\alpha_m = \int^{1}_{-1}\cos \pi x (x^2-1)^m dx$$

then how do I get

$$\alpha_m = \frac{-1}{\pi^2}(2m(2m-1)\alpha_{m-1} + 4m(m-1)\alpha_{m-2})$$

I have to integrate by parts!

But
$$\alpha_n = -\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int^{1}_{-1}\cos \pi x (m(m-1)(x^2-1)^{m-2}4x^2 + 2m(x^2-1)^{m-1})dx$$

I can see how I might be getting closer, but these factors of $x$ are not doing me any favours.

Comment: What is the argument for the cosine, also on the first line did you mean $a_m$ instead of $a_n$?

Comment: oh sorry, the integrand is $\cos\pi x \times (x^2-1)^m$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating by parts once we get:
$$ \alpha_m = \int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2-1)^m\,dx = \frac{m}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}2x\sin(\pi x)\cdot(x^2-1)^{m-1}\,dx$$
and by integrating by parts twice, through $\int 2x\sin(\pi x)\,dx = \frac{2\sin(\pi x)}{\pi^2}-\frac{2x\cos(\pi x)}{\pi}$, we get:
$$ \alpha_m = \frac{m(m-1)}{\pi}\left(\frac{2}{\pi^2}\int_{-1}^{1}2x\sin(\pi x)(x^2-1)^{m-2}\,dx-\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{-1}^{1}x^2\cos(\pi x)(x^2-1)^{m-2}\,dx\right)$$
where the first term in the RHS depends on $\alpha_{m-1}$ and the second term, by writing $x^2$ as $(x^2-1)+1$, depends on $\alpha_{m-1}$ and $\alpha_{m-2}$.